# Setting Virtualbox to widescreen

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, manjaro, resolution

I am currently using Manjaro (Arch Linux 4.9) and VirtualBox 5.1.26. How am I supposed to set the VM resolution to widescreen (eg. 1366 x 768)?

Thanks!

Comment: er, if you have the VBox extensions installed on the client host, just set the window to whichever aspect ratio you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the resolution using `xrandr`. Assuming you can still boot up your computer and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access a command prompt, you can type this to change to automatic resolution:

```
xrandr --display :0 --output VGA1 --auto
```

After the command has finished without any error you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the GUI and it should have the right resolution. Don't forget to change the resolution again, so that the configuration will be saved.

Notes:

1. You may need to change `VGA1` to the name of your display output (type `xrandr --display:0` to see the outputs)
2. If `--auto` isn't smart enough you can change it to e.g.
   `xrandr --display :0 --output VGA1 --mode 1366 x 768`
   , which will change the resolution to 1366 x 768 (again, type `xrandr --display:0` to see the possible resolution modes).

or

Check for the config file which should be this: `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`

Changed the `Resolution` line back to `1366 x 768` and i was good:

```
<property name="Resolution" type="string" value="1366x768"/>
```

Comment: Great to know that your problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the screen size in VirtualBox with:

Machine > Settings > Display > Scale Factor

(I did this after first doing View > Full-screen Mode)